# WinForms Navigated Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, webbrowser-control

i made a winForms application that uses web browser control that enables the user to sign in with his google or facebook account then after getting the information or any error or exception the form which contains the web browser closes and will return back to the main form, i do the following, prepare the request, navigate() using that request then catch the response with the event Navigated.
in the code all is working fine, but when i build as Release and install the application the Navigated event is never fired up, which is really weird since nothing in my code is in debug condition, any ideas how to solve this issue??

**the code at form's load event is:**

```
private void GoogleLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthHelper authHelper = new AuthHelper();

        Uri loginURI = authHelper.GetGoogleAuthURI(_appID, redirectURI);
        GoogleLoginControl.Navigate(loginURI);
    }
```

**the code at the web browser control at Navigated event**

```
private void GoogleLoginControl_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreStaticMembers.ologger.LogToFile("Navigated event with the absolute URL "+ e.Url.AbsoluteUri );
        MessageBox.Show("Navigated event is fired");
        ///used if parameters are empty so ignore the following messages
        bool ignore = false;
        string code = null;

        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.Equals("/connect/login_success.html"))
        {
            AuthHelper authHelper = new AuthHelper();
            //NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(e.Url.Query);
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(e.Url.Query);
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    string jsonResponse = null;
```

and after that i continue with normal authentication and data acquiring, keep in mind that this issue only appears when i build as Release then install the application, also the Navigating even is fired for the web browser control, so does the Load event for the parent form
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
 by the way i also tried to Navigate with the required URL when i initialize the form by calling Initialize function inside the form's constructor, but the same problem appeared,

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Kindly add punctuation as well, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that this problem is related to a compatibility issue related to a DLL file, particularly "Newtonsoft" DLL.